# Center one Svg layer into another Svg

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, center

I am trying to do probably some easy task: wrapp one svg layer into another and center it.

In this case it is a simple arrow (well, a svg path) which should be nested in rectangle (a square shape in this particular matter).

The thing is, I am completely new to this svg subject, so far i only managed to wrap one svg into parent svg, and time is essence :)

I tried to do my own research, but so far i dont see a simple explanation, only how to combine layers, not necessary center it one into another (only as centered in div tag)

Here is a code

```html
 <svg width="38" height="38" viewBox="0 0 38 38" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="37" height="37" rx="9.5" stroke="#222426"/>
    <svg width="18" height="12" viewBox="0 0 18 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0.66732 0.999999L8.72964 10.8681C8.76363 10.9095 8.80536 10.9428 8.85208 10.9655C8.89879 10.9882 8.94943 11 9.00065 11C9.05187 11 9.10251 10.9882 9.14922 10.9655C9.19594 10.9428 9.23767 10.9095 9.27167 10.8681L17.334 1" stroke="#222426" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    </svg>
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: Add `x="10" y="13"` to the inner svg. The main idea is that the center of the main svg is x=19 y=19 ( 38 / 2 ) In order to center the arrow you need to move it 19 - 18/2 in x and 19 - 12/2 in y

Comment: Thanks, i tried to wrapp into another svg but probably ended with wrong x and y values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, i just solved it :D

I must wrap once more an svg path (arrow) into ANOTHER svg layer and specify the x and y atrribute in order to change position of the arror path.

Heres the code now

```html
<svg width="38" height="38" viewBox="0 0 38 38" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="37" height="37" rx="9.5" stroke="#222426"/>
      <svg
        x="10"
        y="13">
    <svg width="18" height="12" viewBox="0 0 18 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0.66732 0.999999L8.72964 10.8681C8.76363 10.9095 8.80536 10.9428 8.85208 10.9655C8.89879 10.9882 8.94943 11 9.00065 11C9.05187 11 9.10251 10.9882 9.14922 10.9655C9.19594 10.9428 9.23767 10.9095 9.27167 10.8681L17.334 1" stroke="#222426" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    </svg>
    </svg>
    
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the thing you want to centre inside another svg as it can have percentage based values. On the 'outer' svg, specify the properties you wish to maintain like the width or height. If unspecified, the width will be 100% of whatever contains the svg.

In the inner svg, specify the x position and width in percentages to match your needs. For instance x=25%, width=50%, and set your scaling requirements e.g.  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 800 52"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="52px">
    <svg x="25%" width="50%" opacity=".5" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 800 51.27">
        <path d="m20.1,44.79c8.47.33,16.98.18,25.46.19,8.12,0,16.25.01,24.37.02,15.61.01,284.23.06,299.84.12,31.81.11,63.63.28,95.44.29,20.41,0,294.81-.05,315.22-.17,1.1,0,1.1-1.66,0-1.66-34.73.22-323.47.22-358.2.11-31.11-.1-62.22-.27-93.33-.26-8.99,0-270.97.02-279.96.08-9.6.06-19.25-.04-28.84.46-.55.03-.55.8,0,.82h0Z"/>
        <path d="m402.79,44.59c0,1.5-1.26,2.72-2.81,2.72s-2.81-1.22-2.81-2.72,1.26-2.72,2.81-2.72,2.81,1.22,2.81,2.72Z"/>
        <g>
            <path d="m27.7,44.4c0,.85-.72,1.55-1.6,1.55s-1.6-.69-1.6-1.55.72-1.55,1.6-1.55,1.6.69,1.6,1.55Z"/>
            <path d="m36.4,44.4c0,1.38-1.16,2.51-2.59,2.51s-2.59-1.12-2.59-2.51,1.16-2.51,2.59-2.51,2.59,1.12,2.59,2.51Z"/>
            <path d="m44.74,48.69c-2.43,0-4.41-1.93-4.41-4.29s1.98-4.29,4.41-4.29,4.41,1.93,4.41,4.29-1.98,4.29-4.41,4.29Zm0-7.09c-1.61,0-2.91,1.25-2.91,2.79s1.31,2.79,2.91,2.79,2.91-1.25,2.91-2.79-1.31-2.79-2.91-2.79Z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="m773.3,44.4c0,.85.72,1.55,1.6,1.55s1.6-.69,1.6-1.55-.72-1.55-1.6-1.55-1.6.69-1.6,1.55Z"/>
            <path d="m764.6,44.4c0,1.38,1.16,2.51,2.59,2.51s2.59-1.12,2.59-2.51-1.16-2.51-2.59-2.51-2.59,1.12-2.59,2.51Z"/>
            <path d="m756.26,48.69c-2.43,0-4.41-1.93-4.41-4.29s1.98-4.29,4.41-4.29,4.41,1.93,4.41,4.29-1.98,4.29-4.41,4.29Zm0-7.09c-1.61,0-2.91,1.25-2.91,2.79s1.31,2.79,2.91,2.79,2.91-1.25,2.91-2.79-1.31-2.79-2.91-2.79Z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```